# Compare the prediction performance of models in different Git versions scheduled by Jenkins

Tags: git, jenkins, comparison, version, modeling

I have built 3 classification models as part of a project which have been checked into Git repository with different version ID. I need to compare the performance of these models overnight that are scheduled by Jenkins.

At the moment, my approach is to create a branch for each model and tell Jenkins which branch I need to run. However, it becomes not sustainable as the version of models grow.

One possible solution I can think of is that I could specify the version of the model to run in the Jenkins schedule, not only branch in the Jenkins schedule. Unfortunately, I did not find how to do this. Do you know how this is possible? If this method is not possible, is there any alternative way to carry out the performance comparison?

Answer (score 1):

If you use a single branch you may want to "tag" the different versions of the model and ask Jenkins to checkout a specific revision which is tagged with the desired version number.
git tagging: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Tagging

Jenkins: Branch Specifier (blank for default): tags/[tag-name]

Comment: Thanks! Just found another way to do this if a user does not specify the tag. You could use the commit ID which is always available.

Answer (score 0):

Just to answer my own questions:commit ID can be used to build a particular version of the code repository